# Error 404 when calling ajax in dialog onOk

Tags: django, ajax, http-status-code-404, ckeditor4.x

```
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('nameDialog', function (editor) {
       ...

       onOk: function () {
        $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'util:upload_doc_to_s3'  %}",
                // url : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/util/upload_doc_to_s3/",
                type : "POST",
                data : {
                    fileObj: fileObj,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                // handle a successful response
                success : function(json) {
                    console.log('done triggered');
                    console.log(response)
                },

                // handle a non-successful response
                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    console.log('fail triggered');
                },
            });
        }

    }
```

In the above code, I got an invalid URL `404 error`.

I was expecting this url.

expecting URL: http://localhost:8000/util/upload_doc_to_s3/

However, it become this,

http://localhost:8000/util/product_tab/edit/cfd/13/%7B%%20url%20'util:upload_doc_to_s3'%20%20%%7D?callback=jQuery2220038196995506981635_1575017580560 404 (Not Found)

In the url, the `util/product_tab/edit/cfd/13/` is the current path of page.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Looks like you template is not rendered by Django, please share your view

Comment: Hi @Hanzla, you are right. thanks for your reply! The template is not rendered by Django which mean i shouldnt use my Django template. Got it worked already! Thanks!